# What is the smallest unit of eos?

Tags: tokens, eosio.token

How many decimal places can eos be set to? I want to send the smallest amount of eos to another account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Token precision (number of decimal places) is defined when executing the `create` function on the eosio.token contract.

You pass max supply to the token contract, which will include the precision.

In the case of the EOS token, it is divisiable up to 4 decimal places.

**0.0001 Is the smallest unit of EOS.**

Comment: does the minimal unit have a special name, like Wei in Eth? I've found that SYS is a new name of EOS: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/487/6408 but haven't found anything about subunit